# Example Terms of Service for OSS software hosted on Google platform?

Tags: terms-of-service

I've written a relatively simple extension for Google Sheets that is open source and free, but recently Google have changed their policies and require all such extensions to include a Terms of Service. Not being a lawyer, nor having any money to pay for lawyer as I'm not getting any money from this product, I'm wondering if there are any templates or examples that people can point me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer...

Depending on which license you use, there may be provided examples. For instance, the folks at gnu.org have a "How to use this license" type document

https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.en.html

And it includes the following as suggested in order to use GPLv3-or-later -

> This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at
>   your option) any later version.
>
> This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
>   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
>   General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>   along with this program.  If not, see https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

Note specifically the middle paragraph.  This is the type of language you are looking for.

Edit your question to include info on exactly what license you want to use - the license creator has likely done the work for you already.

Comment: Thanks, but is a license the same as terms of service?